# Create regular expression to get attributes in CSS

Tags: regex, powershell

Im trying to get in a css all the atributes that aren't less variables inside the { }

So far my RegExp is like this:

```
\s*[a-zA-Z-]*:[^@].*?;
```

Example Text

```css
@footerBackground: @Color1;
@footerText: @Color3;
footer          { background:@footerBackground url(images/bg.transp.fabric-45degreee_fabric.png) repeat; box-shadow:0 -1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); bottom:0; color:@footerText; position:absolute; width:100%; }
footer a        { color:@footerLink !important; }
footer a:hover  { color:darken(@footerLink, 15%) !important; text-decoration:none; }
#footer-widgets { border-bottom:1px darken(@footerBackground,10%) dotted; padding:20px 0; }
```

Can anyone tell me how can i do this expression?

example

```
discart if have @ - color:darken(@tuningfooterLink, 15%) !important;
get - text-decoration:none;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know powershell, but ill have a go at the regex:

`([a-zA-Z_-]+:[^}{@]*?;)` should capture any css class attribute not containing `@` I think

```
( #group1
  [a-zA-Z_-] #Character class matching a-z, A-Z, _ and -
  + #match character class atleast once (applies to [a-zA-Z_-])
  : #match a :
  [^}{@] #Character class matchting all characters except {, }. and @
  + #match character class atleast once (applies to [^}{@])
  ? #dont be a greedy matcher (applies to +)
  ; #match a ; the closing char for any valid CSS rule
) #close group1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it work great with this expression but is getting also the initialization of the variables less, i update my example above, can you have a look?

Comment: hmm thats maybe a powershell issue, seems to work fine in ruby, http://rubular.com/r/YRG82Fk2X6

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Try this:

```
$a = Get-Content .\your.css
$b = $a | % { $_ -replace "({\s*[a-zA-Z-]*:[^@].*\))(.*;)(\s*}$)", '$1$3' }
```

Then you can do

```
Set-Content -Path .\yourchanged.css -Value $b.
```

One liner can be:

```
( Get-Content .\your.css ) |  % { $_ -replace "({\s*[a-zA-Z-]*:[^@].*\))(.*;)(\s*}$)", '$1$3' } | Set-Content -Path .\yourchanged.css
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm using this http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to test the expressions but with my expression i dont know how to discart ( color:darken(@tuningfooterLink, 15%) !important; )

Comment: I'm trying to remove all atributes inside { } that don't have variables (represented by @variable) . In footer a:hover  { color:darken(@footerLink, 15%) !important; text-decoration:none; }
 i want to remove for example "text-decoration:none;"

Comment: It's almost there, i will see what i can do more with your expression

Comment: Hope can help you to reach your goal!